# My cookies don't persist after i restart the browser

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, cookie-session

I am using `cookieSession` to deal with session matters. No problem except when i restart the browser, my session doesn't persist. I wish sessions remain active every time and never expire.

Here is my setup

```
app.use(cookieSession({
  name: 'xxxx',
  keys: ['xxxxx', 'xxxx'],
  cookie: { secure: true,
            httpOnly: true,
            domain: 'mydomain.com',

            expires: 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999 
          }
  })
);
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [cookie-session readme](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session/blob/65cf90edef4a128c5c372c9f32ddabe53f54a996/README.md), I don't think you need to nest your options in a `cookie` property. Also, `expires` takes a `Date` object; you should pass that value as `maxAge` instead if you wish to give it the number of milliseconds until the cookie expires. Keep in mind that all cookies expire per the [cookie specification](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2965.html), so the best you can do is set an expiration time very far in the future.

Try this:

```
app.use(cookieSession({
  name: 'xxxx',
  keys: ['xxxxx', 'xxxx'],
  secure: true,
  httpOnly: true,
  domain: 'mydomain.com',
  maxAge: 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999 
  })
);
```

EDIT: Some older browsers don't support `maxAge`, so `expires` might be better for compatibility. Also, watch out for overflow in `maxAge`; a negative value may cause the browser to expire the cookie immediately or when the browser closes. Consider using `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However still the same issue. All cookies are removed when i restart the browser. Very strange.

Comment: Are you sure a cookie is being sent back from the server?

Comment: Solved ! thanks. Indeed the problem was related to the `Date`. `9999999999999999999` was an invalid date and i incorrectly set another timestamp to `expires` which expects a `Date` object. After i set `new Date(Date.now() + 86400 * 1000 * 1000)`  Now my issue is fixed . Thank you Doug !